# How to print element(s) in Arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, multidimensional-array

I need to find the element(s) of a 2D-Array of i-th row and j-th column.
I simply write T[i][j] and get correct result, but I get unintended results when I go for range of 'elements'

```
T = [[11, 12, 5, 2], [15, 6,10], [10, 8, 12, 5], [12,15,8,6]]
print(T[1][2])
```

`Out[2]: 10`

```
print(T[1:3][:2])
```

`Out[3]: [[15, 6, 10], [10, 8, 12, 5]]`

I wish to print the 2nd,3rd rows having 1st and 2nd columns, but output I got as entire 2nd and 3rd row instead.

Comment: that kind of double indexing requires special structures, for example `numpy` arrays. Alternatively, you have to construct the result with just your relevant values instead, using old school iteration.

Comment: You do not have an array; you have a `list`.

Comment: You get what you ask for: `T[1:3]` --> get me the 1 to 3rd sublist of `T` which happens to be `[[15, 6,10], [10, 8, 12, 5], [12,15,8,6]]` and then you ask for `[:2]` of that which happens to be `[[15, 6,10], [10, 8, 12, 5]`.

Comment: [understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)

Answer (score 1):

you can not split columns by `[:2]`, `[:2]` in `T[1:3][:2]` means the first two elements(rows here) of `T[1:3]`. you can do this in `numpy`, but can not in `list`.

you can try this instead:

```
[t[:2] for t in T[1:3]]
```

output:

```
[[15, 6], [10, 8]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider the output of the first index operation:

```
T = [[11, 12, 5, 2], [15, 6,10], [10, 8, 12, 5], [12,15,8,6]]
print(T[1:3])
Out: [[15, 6, 10], [10, 8, 12, 5]]
```

So you second indexing operation is just getting the first two elements of this, which are the compelete rows.

What you are looking for:

```
print([i[:2] for i in T[1:3]])
Out: [[15, 6], [10, 8]]
```

This first gets the outer element, and then the inner element.